# Android 4.2.2 does not load google maps for my application

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an android application (build with Phonegap) that requires to display the current location of a user and to load KMZ file (with poly lines) on Google Map (use of google map api).

My application loads the map on a specific zoom level (11) and map is centered based on user's current location (reduce data consumption). I noticed that for android OS 4.2.2  the map is  not loaded at all, message displayed " access denied to your current position".

On the other hand map is loaded correctly for android OS 4.1.2, 4.3, 4.4 (not get any message).

Is this a security issue/bug for android 4.2.2? 
Or it is a bug related to the Phonegap I use to build the APK?
How can I resolve this issue? Is there any configuration I need to do in the mobile?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share you code how you are calling Google API?

Comment: src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false&language=el&key=< MY API KEY>

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to see the HTML code piece where you are calling maps and possibly the JS code too.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on Android 4.2.2 or any other supported version. There might be a mistake in your code settings.

I just re-confirmed by creating a sample App.

**Steps:**

(1) Include **Google API Key and Maps jS link** in the html header section

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <meta charset="utf-8" />
>         <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
>         <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
>         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height" />
>         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
>         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_VALUE_&sensor=true"></script>
>         <title>Hello World</title>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>           <b>Road View</b>
>             <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 200px"></div>  
>             <b>Street View</b>          
>           <div id="pano" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
>           <b>Live Traffic Update View</b>
>           <div id="traffic" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
>
>         <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
>         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>  
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```

(2) In the **index.js** file declare following function to render maps

```
var app = {
         initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        }, 
        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        }, 
        onDeviceReady: function() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
            app.renderMap();
        }, 
        receivedEvent: function(id) {
        },
        renderMap: function() {
            // --- Road View 
            var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573, -71.098326);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: fenway,  zoom: 11
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            // ---- Street View
            var panoramaOptions = {
                position: fenway,
                pov: {  heading: 34, pitch: 10    }
            };
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
            map.setStreetView(panorama); 

            // ---- Live Traffic View
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.04924594193164, -118.24104309082031);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: myLatlng
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('traffic'), mapOptions);
            var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
            trafficLayer.setMap(map);
        }
    };

    app.initialize();
```

(3) Add permission in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

(4) Set your project API level to your desired version, for instance 4.2.2
(5) Run App on device and it should show three different types of Map Views ( Road, Street and Live Traffic)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Somehow its NOT showing the AndroidManifest.xml permissions in the results window :(

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0):

This is the JS file code I use to load KML files on map, get current position, display marker:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ehunter.controllers', []).
    controller('RegionListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window',
        function($scope, $http, $window) {
            $http.get('regions.json').success(function(data) {
                $scope.regions = data;
            });
            $scope.openBrowser = function(url){
            $window.open(url, "_blank", "location=yes");

        }
    }])
    .controller('RegionViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
        function($scope, $routeParams) {
          $scope.region = angular.fromJson($routeParams.r);
           var map;
            var src = "MY_SERVER"+ $scope.region.File;

            initialize();


            function initialize() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                    zoom: 11,  
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN 
                });
                loadKmlLayer(src, map);

            }

            function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
                var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
                    suppressInfoWindows: true,
                    preserveViewport: true,   
                    map: map
                }); 

             }

            getLocation();

             function getLocation(){
                  if (navigator.geolocation) {
                     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function displayPosition(position) {

                          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),  
                              map: map
                          });
                         marker.setVisible(true);
                         marker.setMap(map); 
                         map.setCenter(marker.position);  

                        });   

    }}
    }])
```